# Cakephp 3.0 download file

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I asked a question before about file uploading. I managed to get it working and my next step is getting the file to be downloaded by a customer the files may be different formats from videos to PDFs.

I did read about media views, but they where cakephp 2.0. I have found that 2.0 seems to cause problems for me at least.

I can upload my files for uploading if it helps.

Nased on the link Alex posted, how would I call this function in my view this is the function based from the cakephp book link

```
public function downloadFile($id)
{
   $file = $this->Attachments->getFile($id);
   // a view.
   $this->response->file(
      $file['files/content'],
      ['download' => true]
   );
   return $this->response;
}
```

Comment: did you read the cookbook? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files

Comment: thanks for the answer I do read the cake book, but whenever I look I never find what i am looking for.

Comment: ok, but did you read the specific part that I linked :)

Comment: I did read the link i did made changes to my original post, I'm not sure if it will work or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a link to that function (using the cakephp default routing) you would do this in your view:

`echo $this->Html->link('Download File', ['controller' => 'Attachments', 'action' => 'download_file', $id]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function download(){
    $file_path = WWW_ROOT.'uploads'.DS.'file_name.doc';
    $this->response->file($file_path, array(
        'download' => true,
        'name' => 'file_name.ppt',
    ));
    return $this->response;
}
```